# iPhone/Android/etc detection, Mootools way?

Tags: iphone, android, mootools, detection

Is there a Mootools way to detect iPhone/Android/others ?
I have this Vanilla JS script :

```
if ( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) ||
navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ||
navigator.userAgent.match(/Palm/i) )
{
   window.location = 'address-to-iphone-site';
}
```

I know how to do this for browsers ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmqjY/), but not for smartphones.
Any help would be welcomed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just have a look in the docs: http://www.mootools.net/docs/core/Browser/Browser

- Browser.Platform.ios - (boolean) True if the platform is iOS.
- Browser.Platform.webos - (boolean) True if the platform is WebOS
- Browser.Platform.android - (boolean) True if the platform is Android

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Handset Detection](http://www.handsetdetection.com) for mobile browser detection & redirection. (Disclaimer : I run Handset Detection). Hope that helps.